# Writestreaming query not writing data into table in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

Can someone help me with this issue.
I have a delta table "orders". this table is loaded with 1000 records using the delta file.
Now we are getting the streaming JSON file which is appending the data into this table.

Readstream dataframe **orderInputDF **:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
orderInputDF = (spark
                .readStream
                .schema(jsonSchema)
                .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
                .json(stream_path).
                withColumn("submitted_at",to_timestamp('submittedAt')).
                withColumn("submitted_yyyy_mm", col('submitted_at').substr(0,7)).
                withColumnRenamed("orderId",'order_id').                
                withColumnRenamed("customerId","customer_id").
                withColumnRenamed("salesRepId","sales_rep_id").
                withColumn("shipping_address_attention", col("shippingAddress.attention")).
                withColumn("shipping_address_address", col("shippingAddress.address")).
                withColumn("shipping_address_city", col("shippingAddress.city")).
                withColumn("shipping_address_state", col("shippingAddress.state")).
                withColumn("shipping_address_zip", col("shippingAddress.zip")).
                withColumn("ingest_file_name",lit(files[0][0])).
                withColumn("ingested_at",current_timestamp()).
                drop("products","shippingAddress","submittedAt")
               )
```

This readstream dataframe is returning 20 records.

Writestream Query is as below

```
orderOutputDF = (orderInputDF
          .writeStream
          .format("delta")
          .format("memory")
          .queryName(orders_table) 
          .outputMode("append")
          .option("checkpointLocation", orders_checkpoint_path)
          .start()
)
```

This query is not appending the data. Everytime it is inserting the new records and deleting the old records.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: remove `.format("memory")`

Comment: After removing the .format(memory), it is asking for the path to load the data l. But in my case we have data frame.

Comment: Yes, you need to point to which file append the data. Or I don’t understand the question…

Comment: @AlexOtt There is no file we are creating as a part of readstream load. All the data from the readstream is loaded into the spark dataframe orderInputDF. **Writestream** is using this datafram to load the data into main table.